# How can I create a hierarchical combobox using WPF?

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

I want to create a hierarchical combobox in WPF. I will be binding the combobox to a collection of class whose structure is given below:

```
Public Class Folder                 
{     
  Public string Name;            
  Public string Path;           
  List<SubFolder> SubFolder;   
}
```

And I want the combobox to look like this:

```
------------------------
| Folder.Name                                                                      
|      SubFolder.Name  |
|      SubFolder.Name  |
|      SubFolder.Name  |
----------------------
------------------------
| Folder.Name           
|      SubFolder.Name  |
|      SubFolder.Name  |
|      SubFolder.Name  |
----------------------
------------------------
| Folder.Name                                                                       
|      SubFolder.Name  |
|      SubFolder.Name  |
|      SubFolder.Name  |
------------------------
```

The user should be able to select either a folder or a sub-folder.

Please tell me how I can do this.

Comment: Is it a nested hierarchy? Can a SubFolder contain more SubFolers?

Answer (score 2):

To make this fit into the model of the combo box, which is an `ItemsControl` that displays a sequential list of discrete items, you're going to need to flatten the hierarchy into a single list.

Because I'm lazy, I'd create a view model that exposes `Padding` and `Text` properties, and then have the code that populates the view model set the `Padding` based on each item's level in the hierarchy.  Then I'd create an item template for the combo box that looked like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
   <TextBlock Padding="{Binding Padding}" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

There are a lot of shortcomings with this approach.  But it's easy to build and it will quickly give you a sense of whether or not this is really the appropriate way to present this information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether or not this solution suits your needs but:

1. Create new WPF application (HierarchicalComboBox for example) and paste the code below instead of Window1.xaml.cs code:

   ```
   public partial class Window1 : Window
   {
       public ObservableCollection<Folder> Folders { get; set; }


   public Window1()
   {
       var folders = new List&lt;Folder&gt;
                     {
                       new Folder()
                         {
                           Name = "First",
                           SubFolders =
                             new ObservableCollection&lt;Folder&gt;
                               {
                                 new Folder() {Name = "FirstFolderFirstSub"},
                                 new Folder() {Name = "FirstFolderSecondSub"},
                                 new Folder() {Name = "FirstFolderThirdSub"}
                               }
                         },
                         new Folder()
                         {
                           Name = "Second",
                           SubFolders =
                             new ObservableCollection&lt;Folder&gt;
                               {
                                 new Folder() {Name = "SecondFolderFirstSub"},
                                 new Folder() {Name = "SecondFolderSecondSub"},
                                 new Folder() {Name = "SecondFolderThirdSub"}
                               }
                         }
                     };
     Folders = new ObservableCollection&lt;Folder&gt;(folders);
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = this;


   }


   }


   public class Folder
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public ObservableCollection<Folder> SubFolders { get; set; } 
   }
   ```
2. Then in Window1.xaml paste the code below:

   ```
   <Window x:Class="HierarchicalComboBox.Window1"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:HierarchicalComboBox="clr-namespace:HierarchicalComboBox" Title="Window1">
       <Window.Resources>
           <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type HierarchicalComboBox:Folder}">
               <StackPanel>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                   <ComboBox Margin="8,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding SubFolders}"/>
               </StackPanel>
           </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
       </Window.Resources>
       <Grid>
           <ItemsControl x:Name="HierarchicalComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
           </ItemsControl>
       </Grid>
   </Window>
   ```

Explanation:

In Window.Resources we declared `HierarchicalDataTemplate` which is to bind our ViewModel class (here it is a `Folder` class) to corresponding View, which is the content of `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

Then in Window1.xaml we write as a content `ItemsControl` which will host our list of folders.

Thats all, you can do it similarly in your solution. Hope this helps. If you have any questions then welcome to comments.

**ABOUT FORMATTING**

I'm sorry for poor formatting but can't do anything with, If some of you have an ability to edit answers, please try to re-format the code examples.

Comment: You have two points numbered with 1. In the second of them, there are only 2 xaml lines that don't seem to be very helpful by themselves. Are you sure you didn't forgot to add anything important?

Comment: I partially fixed the formatting. When you post code in a bullet/numbered list, you need to indent *twice*. Not sure what's going on with the angled brackets in the C# code, though...